# How should i design urls for several consective views redirecting to each other?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have four views redirecting from one to another and here is what am doing but the urls are not working out.

```
def show_item(request,id):
        a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = PartialOrderItemForm(request.POST,instance=a)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():
            order.add_to_order(request,a)
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index',kwargs={'id':a.id})
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        ......
    return render_to_response('item.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the above view redirects to this one below,

```
def show_order(request,id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=order_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            order.remove_from_order(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            order.update_order(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'checkout':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':order_id}))
```

`show_order` redirects to `show_checkout` below

```
def show_checkout(request,id):
    ......
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            order_created = create_order(request,resto)
            ....
            if postdata['submit'] == 'place order':
                reciept_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_reciept')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reciept_url)
    return render(request,'checkout/checkout.html',context)
```

urls.py,

```
url(r'^your_order/(\d+)/$',show_order,name="order_index"),
    url(r'^item/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_item, name="item_order"),
    url(r'^checkout/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),
```

all this breaks at the first redirect giving error `NoReverseMatch`. I am not doing it right, a brief explanation on how i can build urls for search a scenario is very much accepted.

complete traceback of errors

```
Traceback:
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/f4l/live/views.py" in show_item
  140.          url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index',kwargs={'id':a.id})
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  396.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /orders/item/3/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'order_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 3}' not found.
```

> Fixing the problem as catherine suggests, results to exception DoesNotEXist at `Show_checkout`

```
Traceback:
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/f4l/live/views.py" in show_checkout
  59.       resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  131.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  366.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /orders/checkout/3/
Exception Value: Restaurant matching query does not exist
```

complete `checkout_view`

```
def show_checkout(request,id):
    """checkout form to collect order information"""
    if order.is_empty(request):
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            order_created = create_order(request,resto)
            order_number = order_created.id
            if order_number:
                request.session['order_number'] = order_number
            if postdata['submit'] == 'place order':
                reciept_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_reciept')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reciept_url)
    else:
        form = forms.CheckoutForm
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,'checkout/checkout.html',context)
```

Comment: complete trace back of errors?

Comment: just did add the traceback

Comment: now I know the error. Your codes is Ok, it just the system cannot find the id = 3 in your data

Comment: alright so what do you think is the solution..and an explanation on how i can go about such a situation in the future would be helpful...

Comment: i just included the the traceback for this new error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `order_id` instead of `id`. The `order_id` has no value.

```
def show_order(request,id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    .......

url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_order,name="order_index"),
url(r'^item/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_item, name="item_order"),
url(r'^checkout/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),
```

Comment: this works but before i accept answer, there is still a problem. so `show_item` redirects perfectly with item id to `show_order`, which also redirects to `show_checkout` with the item id, when i submit the form at `show_check out` it breaks giving error `DoesNotExist`.let me edit the question.

Comment: The system can't find the restaurant with id=3. did you check your database?

Comment: apparently my views keep carrying the value of the item id from `show_item`

Comment: I need to see your template form codes and complete your show_checkout views

Comment: i just did....@ the comment above about system, it is right, the system is right, there is no restaurant with id 3. thats the id of the item that is being carried in the urls from `show_item`

Comment: I think you need to fix your answer first. What you said about it's item id. You need to pass the restaurant id. or maybe you have field restaurant in your item?

Comment: yes i actually have a restaurant fk field in model item. so how do i use this to my advantage..

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':item.restaurant.id}))`

Comment: that does not work, returns the same error but am going to accept your answer anyway because it worked in the first place..

Comment: your right...i just fixed it by getting the restaurant id in another way..let me also answer the question showing how i just i got the restaurant id in another way.

Answer (score 0):

> How whole problem is solved..thanks to Catherine
>   `show_order` had to have item id not order_id i.e
>   was supposed to be

```
def show_order(request,id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
```

and not,

```
def show_order(request,id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=order_id)
```

also in show_checkout i had to get restaurant id in different way

not this

```
def show_checkout(request,id):
    ......
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
```

but this

```
def show_checkout(request,id):
    .......
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            order_created = create_order(request,item)
```

and in `create_order`

```
 def create_order(request,obj):
        """create new order containing each orderitem instance,save order and empty the order."""
        anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
        resto = Item.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
        orders = Order()

        checkout_form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=orders)
        checkout = checkout_form.save(commit=False)

        checkout.created_by = anon_user
        checkout.modified_by = anon_user
        checkout.restaurant = resto.owner
```